# how to retrieve text from a textbox that was created programmatically in swift 2.0?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am trying to take the text from multiple text fields that are added programmatically as the user needs them by pressing a button and add it to an array to use on the next view controller when press the submit button however I cant figure out how to do it. This is my code for how I create the text fields when the button is pressed.

```
var numberOfTasks = 1

var i = 0


@IBAction func addTaskButton(sender: AnyObject)
{
    numberOfTasks = numberOfTasks + 1

    addNewTask()


}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    scrollViewTAR.contentSize.height = 50
    addNewTask()
}

func addNewTask(){

    var yPosition:CGFloat = 10
    var xPosition:CGFloat = 0
    var textWidth:CGFloat = scrollViewTAR.frame.width-20

    for (i=0; i<numberOfTasks; i = i + 1){

    var textField: UITextField = UITextField()
    textField.frame = CGRectMake(xPosition, yPosition, textWidth, 30)
    textField.placeholder = "Enter Task \(i + 1) Here"
    textField.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15)
    textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect
    textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.No
    textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.Default
    textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done
    textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.WhileEditing;

    scrollViewTAR.addSubview(textField)
    scrollViewTAR.frame.size.width = view.frame.width-20
    scrollViewTAR.center = view.center
    scrollViewTAR.contentSize.height += 20
    yPosition += 35

    }
```

If you need any of my other code just ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are running into is one of scoping.  When you declare

```
var textField: UITextField = UITextField()
```

That means that this texfield is **scoped** only within this function

So you have a few options

1) change your function to:

```
func addNewTask() -> UITextField
```

and have it return `textField`

2) make `textField` a class level construct

```
var textfield: UITextField?
func addNewTask() {

// lots of code

self.textField = UITextField()
}
```

In either case, however, when you are accessing the value of the text you refer to the

`.text` property

[image]

And you can simply do this by:

`textField.text = "HELLO"`

Answer (score 1):

Don't declare your `textField` in a function. Declare it in your `ViewController` class and edit it in your function. Then you can reference it by:

```
textField.text
```